# pyfiglet issues in printing ascii art

Tags: python, ascii

PROBLEM 1:

how can i remove these external text parts from my ASCII text
in python (i am using pyfiglet ) ? it appears well in VScode
terminal but when i run it from python shell it just appear so
bad like this :

```
←[33m___________________________________________________←[0m


←[34m    ____  _                  _ __     __   ______
   / __ \(_)___  ____ _     (_) /_   / /   \ \ \ \
  / /_/ / / __ \/ __ `/    / / __/  / /     \ \ \ \
 / _, _/ / / / / /_/ /    / / /_   /_/      / / / /
/_/ |_/_/_/ /_/\__, /    /_/\__/  (_)      /_/_/_/
              /____/
←[33m←[0m

←[33m___________________________________________________←[0m


←[32m<<<  WELCOME TO RING IT APPLICATION  >>>
←[0m←[31m

Please enter how many alarms you want to set ?

←[0m
←[95m>>>
```

here is the header code :

```
ascii_art = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Ring  it ! >>>" , font="slant") + colorama.Fore.YELLOW
ascii_art_colored = colored(ascii_art , "blue")
print(colored("___________________________________________________" , "yellow"))
print("\n\n" +ascii_art_colored + "\n")
print(colored("___________________________________________________" , "yellow")+"\n\n")
print(colored("<<<  WELCOME TO RING IT APPLICATION  >>>\n" , "green") + colored("\n\nPlease enter how many alarms you want to set ? \n\n" , "red"))
```

i want to remove these ( ←[33m ←[0m ←[32  )
and it appear like this :

```
___________________________________________________


    ____  _                  _ __     __   ______  
   / __ \(_)___  ____ _     (_) /_   / /   \ \ \ \ 
  / /_/ / / __ \/ __ `/    / / __/  / /     \ \ \ \
 / _, _/ / / / / /_/ /    / / /_   /_/      / / / /
/_/ |_/_/_/ /_/\__, /    /_/\__/  (_)      /_/_/_/ 
              /____/


___________________________________________________


<<<  WELCOME TO RING IT APPLICATION  >>>


Please enter how many alarms you want to set ?
```

PROBLEM 2 :
also i have an issue with it color ... it just get
cmd theme color  not that color i set for it with termcolor2 or
colorama ...

Comment: Looks like whatever terminal you are outputting into does not support ansi colour codes: that's what those `[0` characters mean.

Comment: Did you call `colorama.init()` after importing it?

Comment: it worked @snakecharmerb thanks i just added colorama.init() as you said ... but  can you explain what it does ?

Comment: See https://github.com/tartley/colorama#initialisation